# What do repeated ８s mean in internet slang?

Tags: internet-slang

I was watching a live video stream the other day.  To my surprise, other viewers kept flooding the chat with the number eight!  My screen kept filling up with messages like these:

> `８８８８８８８８８８８８８８８８８８８８８８８８８８８８８８８８８８８`
>   `➑➇➑➇➑➇➑➇➑➇➑➇➑➇➑➇➑➇➑➇➑➇➑➇➑➇➑➇➑➇➑➇➑➇➑➇➑➇➑➇➑➇➑➇`
>   `8８8８8８8８8８8８8８8８8８8８8８8８8８8８8８8８8８8８8８8８8８8８`

What do these messages mean?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As you can see from these references:

- http://netyougo.com/twitter/1652.html
- http://www.paradisearmy.com/doujin/pasok_8888.htm

Streams of the number eight such as `８８８８` represent **applause**.  They're read [`パチパチ`](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0na&p=%E3%83%91%E3%83%81%E3%83%91%E3%83%81), the sound of hands clapping together one after another in applause, as in the phrase `パチパチと拍手する`.

The second reference above also explains the derived slang terms `７７７７` and `９９９９`, which might be of interest:

- `７７７７` means that something wasn't good enough to applaud, so it only got `７` instead of `８`;
- `９９９９` expresses the opposite, that something was even better than `８８８８` would imply.